# process consumes all cpu and cannot be killed?

Tags: debian, cpu

all of a sudden a process appeared on my unix server (debian).
I disabled and removed the nexus.service. Eventually I removed the files found by "whereis nexus". But that did not help.

How can I invastigate and solve the issue?

```
top - 23:10:50 up 44 min,  1 user,  load average: 2,62, 2,29, 1,55
Tasks: 100 total,   1 running,  98 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s): 99,7 us,  0,3 sy,  0,0 ni,  0,0 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem :  8009168 total,  1632252 free,  4713448 used,  1663468 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  3145724 total,  3145724 free,        0 used.  2998328 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND    
15305 nexus     20   0 2737692   2,3g   2132 S 198,7 30,0  31:09.11 httpyyy    
 3497 root      20   0  294912  13172   5020 S   0,3  0,2   0:02.43 docker-con+
14696 jenkins   20   0 4732252 997928  23428 S   0,3 12,5   0:54.62 java       
14942 jenkins   20   0 4677072 957860  14472 S   0,3 12,0   1:02.58 java       
15400 root      20   0  161872   2184   1556 R   0,3  0,0   0:00.09 top
```

Comment: My first thought was malware.  Searching for `httpyyy` turns up no relevant results for me

Comment: The process name is `httpyyy` being run by a user named `nexus`.  Have a look at the contents of `/proc/15305/` to see what that process is up to and where it could be running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this service "respawning?" I.e., does a new process (with a new/different process id (PID)) appear in the output of `top`? (Yes, I realize that this is viewable through `ps` and the /proc filesystem; trying to keep it simple).

If the process is respawning, you need to look at the service definition (this could be via upstart/systemd/etc).  Since the process isn't running as root (that's GOOD), you shouldn't have any problems killing it.  Poke-around the /etc/ directory (recursively) to find the service files.